# Race conditions with OpenMP

Tags: openmp, race-condition

I need to fill 2D array `(tmp[Ny][Nx])` while each cell of the array gets an integral (of some function) as a function of free parameters. Since I deal with a very large arrays (here I simplified my case), I need to use `OpenMP` parallelism in order to speed my calculations up. Here I use simple `#pragma omp parallel for` directive.

Without using `#pragma omp parallel for`, the code executes perfectly. But adding the parallel directive, produces race conditions in the output.

I tried to cure it by making `private(i,j,par)`, it did not help.

P.S. I use VS2008 Professional with OpenMP 2.0 and under WIndows 7 OS

Here is my code: (a short sample)

```c
testfunc(const double* var, const double* par)
{
    // here is some simple function to be integrated over
    // var[0] and var[1] and two free parameters par[0] and par[1]
    return ....
}

#define Nx 10000
#define Ny 10000
static double tmp[Ny][Nx];

int main()
{    
    double par[2]; // parameters
    double xmin[]={0,0} // limits of 2D integration
    double xmax[]={1,1};// limits of 2D integration

    double val,Tol=1e-7,AbsTol=1e-7;
    int i,j,NDim=2,NEval=1e5;

#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,par,val) 
    for (i=0;i<Nx;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<Ny;j++)
        {
            par[0]=i;
            par[1]=j*j;
            adapt_integrate(testfunc,par, NDim, xmin, xmax,
                            NEval, Tol, AbsTol, &val, &err);
            // adapt_integrate - receives my integrand, performs
            // integration and returns a result through "val"
            tmp[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

It produces race conditions at the output. I tried to avoid it by making all internal variables (`i`,`j`,`par` and `val`) private, but it doesn't help.

P.S. Serial version (#threads=1) of this code runs properly.

Comment: `err` should be private, too, but I doubt that's the problem.  Are you sure `adapt_integrate` and `testfunc` are theadsafe -- do they have static variables, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it's most probably one of the functions you call that's not thread safe.

Comment: It makes sense! How to verify that my functions are thread safe? Just make sure that all variables I pass are of type const?

Comment: @Pomeron: Look at the documentation if it specifies their threadsafety. If it doesn't (or doesn't exist) look at the source code and watch for non const access to shared variables (non const parameters or global variables most likely). If it isn't specified and you don't have the code assume they aren't.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! I finally solved this problem by declaring my parameters as global (I know, it's not safe!!!) and adding the

Comment: #pragma omp threadprivate(GlobPar) directive.

Comment: @Pomeron: Instead of writing the solution in the question, you should write it as an answer to your question and accept that, at least when there are no helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the question. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **The problem Solved!**
>
> I defined parameters of integration as global and used `#pragma omp threadprivate(parGlob)` directive for them. Now it works like a charm. I've been thinking that `private()` and `threadprivate()` have the same meaning, just different ways of implementations, but they do not.
>
> So, playing with these directives may give a correct answer. Another thing is that defining iterator `i` inside the first `for` loop gives additional 20%-30% speed up in performance. So, the fastest version of the code looks now as:

```
testfunc(const double* var, const double* par)
    {
       .......
    }

    #define Nx 10000
    #define Ny 10000
    static double tmp[Ny][Nx];
    double parGlob[2]; //<- Here are they!!!
    #pragma omp threadprivate(parGlob)  // <-Magic directive!!!!

    int main()
    {    
 // Not here !!!! ->       double par[2]; // parameters
        double xmin[]={0,0} // limits of 2D integration
        double xmax[]={1,1};// limits of 2D integration

        double val,Tol=1e-7,AbsTol=1e-7;
        int j,NDim=2,NEval=1e5;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(j,val)  // no `i` inside `private` clause
        for (int i=0;i<Nx;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<Ny;j++)
            {
                parGlob[0]=i;
                parGlob[1]=j*j;
                adapt_integrate(testfunc,par, NDim, xmin, xmax,
                                NEval, Tol, AbsTol, &val, &err);
                tmp[i][j] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```